# Remove the last comma from the for loop

Tags: python, sql

I tried to create a sql command using python for loop:

```
var_list = ["lshank_time","lshank_accel_x","lshank_accel_y","lshank_accel_z","lshank_gyro_x","lshank_gyro_y","lshank_gyro_z","lshank_mag_x","lshank_mag_y","lshank_mag_z","rshank_time","rshank_accel_x","rshank_accel_y","rshank_accel_z","rshank_gyro_x","rshank_gyro_y","rshank_gyro_z","sacrum_time","sacrum_accel_x","sacrum_accel_y","sacrum_accel_z","sacrum_gyro_x","sacrum_gyro_y","sacrum_gyro_z","sacrum_mag_x","sacrum_mag_y","sacrum_mag_z","grf_time","grf_x","grf_y","grf_z"]

# create table
sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + tableName + ' ('
for field in var_list:
    sql = sql + field + ' FLOAT(53), '
sql = sql + ")" + ';\n'
```

It turns out that the output for the last variable ends with "grf_z FLOAT(53),"
how should I solve this?

Comment: Don't concatenate in a loop. Make a list and use `', '.join()`. Then there's nothing to remove.

Comment: @AlbertoHanna There's a space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a f-string and python string `join` method to get what you want:

```py
sql = f"CREATE TABLE {tableName} ({', '.join(field + ' FLOAT(53)' for field in var_list)});\n"

print(sql)
```

This will generate the follwing assuming `TableName` is `foo`

```
CREATE TABLE foo (lshank_time FLOAT(53), lshank_accel_x FLOAT(53), lshank_accel_y FLOAT(53), lshank_accel_z FLOAT(53), lshank_gyro_x FLOAT(53), lshank_gyro_y FLOAT(53), lshank_gyro_z FLOAT(53), lshank_mag_x FLOAT(53), lshank_mag_y FLOAT(53), lshank_mag_z FLOAT(53), rshank_time FLOAT(53), rshank_accel_x FLOAT(53), rshank_accel_y FLOAT(53), rshank_accel_z FLOAT(53), rshank_gyro_x FLOAT(53), rshank_gyro_y FLOAT(53), rshank_gyro_z FLOAT(53), sacrum_time FLOAT(53), sacrum_accel_x FLOAT(53), sacrum_accel_y FLOAT(53), sacrum_accel_z FLOAT(53), sacrum_gyro_x FLOAT(53), sacrum_gyro_y FLOAT(53), sacrum_gyro_z FLOAT(53), sacrum_mag_x FLOAT(53), sacrum_mag_y FLOAT(53), sacrum_mag_z FLOAT(53), grf_time FLOAT(53), grf_x FLOAT(53), grf_y FLOAT(53), grf_z FLOAT(53));
```